# Enable import assertions for Babel in node.js

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-plugin

```
import data from './data.json' assert {type: "json"};
```

Got the below error message,

```
Add @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions (https://git.io/JUbkv) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.
```

Added the following in `.babelrc` file

```
{
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
    ]
}
```

Anyone else encountered similar issue?